# Can I increase the localstorage on my own computer?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I build a webpage for my own use only, it's for analysis, I need to increase my own local storage, but can't find any info on if or how this is possible. Can it be done?

Comment: local storage is somewhere near unlimited according to my knowledge. but refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values

Answer (score 6):

You can adjust localStorage quota for **Opera** and **Firefox**.
Refer below

> **Opera**: Doesn't actually requires adjusting. You can however change default storage size at which Opera will propose increasing limit. It
>   is defined by Domain Quota For localStorage option. It's value is in
>   kilobytes.

for opera type this in url `opera:config#PersistentStorage|DomainQuotaForlocalStorage`

> **Firefox**: Go to `about:config` and search for **"dom.storage.default_quota"** option. It's value is in kilobytes.
>
> AFAIK, there's no way to adjust quotas for Chrome/Safari/IE.

Check your local storage size here : https://arty.name/localstorage.html

Comment: What about the other browsers as of May 2022? Not IE of course, not even MS cares about that anymore.